# JavaFX: Draw drag'n'drop visuals in a TreeView

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, scenebuilder

How can I show orange lines in the `TreeView` as in the hierarchy panel of the JavaFX Scene Builder?

[image: TreeView Drag Marker]

I managed to draw the horizontal line in my `treeCell.setOnDragOver()` method, but it needs to compensate the border width, i. e. it just subtracts the border width from the padding of `.tree-cell` in [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/controls/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css). However I think there must be a more elegant way.

Code snippet from my `TreeViewDragDrop.java`:

```
treeCell.setOnDragDetected(
    // ...
    treeCell.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #eea82f; -fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0; " +
        "-fx-padding: 3 3 1 3")
    //...
)
```

Code snippet from `modena.css`:

```
.tree-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em; /* 3 */
    -fx-indent: 1em;
}
```